# mongodb DATA_HAS_BEEN_BACKED_UP, missing database

Tags: mongodb

I had database in use called say `"mydb"` that i was using for very long time, over night something have happened and application stopped working, when i tried to find database within files in `/var/lib/mongodb/`, indeed database is missing but instead i found to files:

1. `DATA_HAS_BEEN_BACKED_UP.0`
2. `DATA_HAS_BEEN_BACKED_UP.ns`

so i can only assume that it could be my database, just im not aware of what happened, unfortunately if i change the name to `"mydb"` database is still empty in mongo interface:

```
use mydb
db.mycollection.find()
```

it returns nothing, while database size is quite heavy, i already tried to do:

```
sudo mongorestore --db mydb --drop /var/...path_to_dir...
```

but it returned "i dont know what to do with the file ..."

can someone help?